# Optocoupler EL817 triggering the relay immediately on power up

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, esp8266

[image]

[image]

I have ESP-12F relay board, as per the following circuit diagram, however the 5V relays are triggering the moment power supply is provided to the board. I expect the optocoupler to trigger only when the GPIO pin connected to MCU is pulled down so I'm not sure why this is happening. I have also added a screen shot of Proteus simulation, validating the same. I am confused here.

Comment: If AE is high and RC1-4 are low, the opto LEDs will switch on, thus switching the relay coils on. What is AE? Is this high at power up? Are RC1-4 low at power up?

Comment: Tip: Draw a schematic diagram that actually shows the schema of the circuit. I can't think of any good reason not to draw the relay driver transistors beside and connected to the opto-isolators. Similarly with the voltage regulators. Even in a simple circuit like this trying to find where each of the broken networks goes to wastes a lot of time and can only get worse on more complex circuits. If you're interested, here are some good [Rules-and-guidelines](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics?r=SearchResults&s=1|82.9620).

Comment: i am sure your rules and guidelines for schematics would be helpful. any chance you found the issue in this circuit that i have shared @Transistor

Comment: No, we're awaiting your response to the first comment.

Comment: Can you capture it in your oscilloscope? Can to trace it back to where the glitch stems from?

Answer (score 1):

Your GPIO might be a logic 0 at power up.

Instead, connect pin #2 of the onto to GND, and drive   pin 1 from the MCU (via the 10 k); invert the logic drive in your software.